# Do viscous and inviscid flow have opposite effects on pressure?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, bernoulli-equation, viscosity

Consider flow through the converging and diverging portions of a tube with varying radius:
[image]

In inviscid flow, Bernoulli's equation states that velocity at the throat will be the highest, so this area will have the lowest pressure.

**If the flow is viscous and *locally* fully developed throughout, however, then my intuition says that the throat will have the highest pressure. Is this true?**

I reason this is true because the volume flow rate $Q$ must stay constant in an incompressible flow. If the flow is locally fully developed at each point $x$, then the flow rate is:

$$ Q = \frac{\pi R^4}{8 \mu}(\frac{-dP}{dx})$$

As $R(x)$ decreases, then $\frac{-dP}{dx}$ must increase in the algebraic sense. The only way this is possible, and to keep pressure continuity at the throat, is if the pressure distribution has a maximum at the throat.

**Does viscous flow through a nozzle result in an increase in pressure, opposite of what inviscid flow predicts?**

Comment: No.  Viscous friction is dissipative and always causes the pressure to decrease in the flow direction, while non-viscous inertial effects associated with the Bernoulli equation can result in either a pressure decrease (as in the converging section) or a pressure increase (as in the diverging section).  In viscous flows, both mechanisms are present simultaneously.

Comment: @ChetMiller So let's say the tube was placed vertically so that gravity was the only driving force, and we poured viscous fluid down it. Wouldn't that allow for a pressure increase with flow direction?

Comment: Yes, that is certainly possible.  But the pressure increase would be less with viscous effects in play.  So the viscous effects would contribute a pressure decrease in the flow direction.  Still, I stand corrected.  Thanks @Drew.

Answer (score 1):

Figure 1 shows the distribution of velocity (top) and pressure (bottom) in a laminar flow in a channel of variable cross section with Reynolds number $Re=900$. The minimum pressure  is observed in the minimum cross section, and at some point downstream.
[image: fig1]